# Symfony4 : Fields from two entities in one form

Tags: php, symfony4

Given these two entities :

Income :

```php
class Income
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=12, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $amount;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Document", mappedBy="income")
     */
    private $document;
```

Document :

```php
class Document
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $source;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Income", inversedBy="document")
     */
    private $income;
```

I would like to make a form to create Income entities, with a Document entity attached.

How can I make a Form class containing the following fields ?

- income Title
- income Amount
- document Source (file)

Comment: document Source (file) must be a collection?

Comment: @IhorKostrov There is one file for one Income, isnt a collection for multiple items?